# Шифрование сообщений в Java. Ошибка дешифровки

Tags: java, криптография, rsa

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не мой код конечно, но помогите исправить ошибки. Как видно, с шифрованием справилась программа успешно. А дешифрование началось с ошибок.

**Person.java:**

```java
package com.company;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Person {

    private PrivateKey privateKey;
    public PublicKey publicKey;

    private final Map<String, PublicKey> contacts = new HashMap<>();

    public Person() {
        generateKeyPair();
    }

    private void generateKeyPair() {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

            keyGen.initialize(2048);
            KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

            privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
            publicKey = pair.getPublic();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    public void addFriend(String name, PublicKey publicKey) {
        contacts.put(name, publicKey);
    }

    public String sendMessage(String recipient, String message) {
        PublicKey publicKey = contacts.get(recipient);
        if (publicKey == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("unknown recipient");

        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

            byte[] msgBytes = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(msgBytes);

            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    public String receiveMessage(String cipherText) {
        byte[] encrypted = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText);

        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

            return new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
```

**App.java:**

```java
package com.company;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        Person mrSergey = new Person();
        Person mrIvan = new Person();

        mrIvan.addFriend("Сергей", mrSergey.publicKey);


        String encryptedMessage = mrIvan.sendMessage("koroleviv1996@gmail.com", "Hello world");
        System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + encryptedMessage);

        String decryptedMessage = mrSergey.receiveMessage(encryptedMessage);
        System.out.println("Decrypted message: " + decryptedMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш код работает корректно `receiveMessage(sendMessage("me", "hello"))` возвращает `hello`. Возможно, вы два раза создаете `new Person()`, поэтому у вас сгенерировались две пары ключей. Покажите код, как вы работаете с классом `Person`?

Comment: package com.company;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        Person mrSergey = new Person();
        Person mrIvan = new Person();

        mrIvan.addFriend("koroleviv1996@gmail.com");

        String encryptedMessage = mrIvan.sendMessage("koroleviv1996@gmail.com", "Hello world");
        System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + encryptedMessage);

        String decryptedMessage = mrSergey.receiveMessage(encryptedMessage);
        System.out.println("Decrypted message: " + decryptedMessage);
    }
} Спасибо заранее, видимо тут что-то не прави

Comment: Большое количество кода лучше добавлять в сам вопрос, [отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1306054/edit) ваш вопрос.

Comment: Скорей всего проблема в том, что при добавлении друга вы используете не тот `publicKey`. Чтобы Иван имел возможность зашфировать сообщение Сергею, ему нужен публичный ключ Сергея, а не свой собственный. Посмотрите мой новый [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1306678).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы Ивану зашифровать сообщение для Сергея, недостаточно знать его имя или email, нужен [публичный ключ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BC) Сергея. Добавьте в метод `addFriend()` второй аргумент `publicKey`:

```java
public void addFriend(String name, PublicKey publicKey) {
    contacts.put(name, publicKey);
}
```

И сделайте проперти `publicKey` публичным у класса `Person`:

```java
public PublicKey publicKey;
```

Тогда добавить друга можно будет так:

```java
Person sergey = new Person();
Person ivan = new Person();
ivan.addFriend("Сергей", sergey.publicKey);
```

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=56887:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\IdeaProjects\1\out\production\crypto com.company.App
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: unknown recipient
 at com.company.Person.sendMessage(Person.java:45)
 at com.company.App.main(App.java:11)

Process finished with exit code 1 Получилась такая ошибка после правок( готовый код поправил в основном сообщении

Comment: Я написал имя `Сергей` в качестве примера. Используйте одинаковое имя когда добавляете друга и когда отправляете ему сообщение.

Comment: То есть если делаете `ivan.addFriend("lalala", ...)`, то нужно отправлять сообщение по этому же имени `ivan.sendMessage("lalala", ...)`

Comment: Огромное спасибо)))

Comment: @JohnNetski если помогло, отметьте ответ галочкой слева :)